# asp.net core 1.1 reading streamcontent multipart data

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

How do I split a multipart data received from webex file download service

```
HttpResponseMessage resp;
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SOAPAction", "downloadNBRStorageFile");
       resp = await client.PostAsync("https://njp1wss.webex.com/nbr/services/NBRStorageService", new StringContent(post));
  }
```

The data response looks like

```
        ------=_Part_604_2105194556.1519707163492
    Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
    Content-Id: <AEE7D153C4A643E707C0DFCECB351409>

    --- xml data not going to be used here --- 
    ------=_Part_604_2105194556.1519707163492
    Content-Type: application/octet-stream
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
    Content-Id: <6B9F34D3B0038FFEC76B2C53E8ECC54F>

    --- some data neeeded including filename and recordid is here ---
    ------=_Part_604_2105194556.1519707163492
    Content-Type: application/octet-stream
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
    Content-Id: <B7DD56DF3518FC5CE8D69C569F709FEF>
```

and at the end has the binary file data.
stream content doesn't seem to have multipart support in core.
I looked into https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/ but doesn't seem to work in core 1.1 or I just couldn't figure it out. (can add it to the project but not allowing me to use it)

Using visual studio 2017, in an asp.net core 1.1 projects.

I'm hoping there is a simple mistake I am doing

Comment: Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.4 now supports netstandard2 which will work with Asp.Net Core 2.0. any reason you're still using 1.1?

Comment: I did not want to upgrade any resources if not needed. Usually things go crashing, if its stable keep it, i might just do it now.

Comment: After discussing with my boss for the changes needed to be done, she prefers not to do the upgrade at this time only when we can devote some time to this. Any other simple option, maybe a way that I can extract the code for  HttpContentMultipartExtensions.ReadAsMultipartAsync  is the only thing i really need.

Comment: You could do ReadAsStreamAsync and then use the multipart reader from Microsoft.Extensions.Webutilities

Comment: Thanks Tratcher, That looks like the alternative way to go. But I cannot find any examples for it. After trying few of the methods in it. I cannot waste any more time on it. If you do know any examples that be great if not its fine. Just have to wait for the core upgrade.